# What is the difference between firstOrDefault() and select () when selecting single row

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, lambda

Im new to Linq.

I like this simple lambda expression :

```
crmContext.CallForTags.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CallForText.Contains(callAgainForText)).RowID;
```

which returns me what i want in a single line.

however there is similar linq expression:

```
crmContext.CallForTags.Where(x => x.CallForText.Contains(callAgainForText)).Select(x => x.RowID);
```

i expect this would do the same and return me RowID

but it actually give me error saying :

cannot implicitly convert IQueryable to int

i tried searching on net. but couldnt find similar post??

Can any one help me understand , how does it differ?
Also is there any performance overhead using between two?
and which one is more better approach with regards to performance?

Comment: Your question itself is a answer. Select returns the IQueryable<int> and not a single row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Select` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`. If there is only one element, it will return an `IEnumerable<T>` with one element.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx

`FirstOrDefault` returns a single instance of T.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx

With your first query, you are saying "give me the RowID of the first row where `CallForText` contains the value of `callAgainForText` (or the default for the type if none exists)."

With your second query, you are effectively saying "give me the RowIDs for every row where `CallForText` contains the value of `callAgainForText`." This will **always** give you back an `IEnumerable`, even if it only contains a single item.

You are then trying to assign the result of this query - which returns multiple items - to a single instance of T, which of course, doesn't work.

Comment: Yes correct, it means whenever i need single row i should use FirstOrDefault() and Select() for rest. I guess FirstOrDefault() must be faster if performance is considered.

Answer (score 1):

This portion will give you a complete row

```
//some IQueryable  = crmContext.CallForTags.Where(x => x.CallForText.Contains(callAgainForText));
```

now as you are using select to have a value of single column then try taking it in a int variable like above ait wont work as it return an IEnumerable

```
Int32 test = crmContext.CallForTags.Where(x => x.CallForText.Contains(callAgainForText)).RowID;
```

When you use the `where` then `column name` it gives a single value, or `FirstorDefault()` for complete row.

FirstOrDefault returns the first element that matches the condition, or null.

Answer (score 0):

when you use select is returns an IEnumerable of the elements you've specified in your lambda expression, SingleOrDefault or FirstorDefault will return the actual type not an enumerable of it.

Answer (score 0):

In the first expression, you ask to be returned only one result if there are any and accessing its `RowID`property (possible `NullReferenceException` there), which I assume is of `int` type.

In the second expression you are asking to filter a list based on your condition and then asking to retrieve `RowID` properties of each item in the result. I assume you want to assign it to a variable of type int which requires an implicit conversion from `IQueryable` to `int`, therefore an error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `RowID` is an int, then:

```
crmContext.CallForTags.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CallForText.Contains(callAgainForText)).RowID
```

will return an int, namely RowID. However, `FirstOrDefault()` returns null for a reference type if the sequence is empty, which means that it will throw a NullReferenceException when you try to dereference `.RowID` in that case.

```
crmContext.CallForTags.Where(x => x.CallForText.Contains(callAgainForText)).Select(x => x.RowID);
```

will return a sequence of all the `RowID` values for all the items that match the predicate `x.CallForText.Contains(callAgainForText)`.

Note that is a sequence, not an int! (By "sequence" I mean `IEnumerable<T>`.)

Answer (score 0):

[`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) returns the first element that matches the predicate, or null (If no matches are found). The return type will be an `int` (if the predicate returns true) since you are selecting the `first` element only, or `null` will be returned if the predicate returns false.

```
rmContext.CallForTags.Where(x => x.CallForText.Contains(callAgainForText)).Select(x => x.RowID);
```

[Selects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) all items that contain `callAgainForText` and returns an `IEnumerable of integers (Which are the Row ID's) or more specifically IEnumerable<int>`